# with xcode, how to define preprocessor macros from the output of a command?

Tags: xcode, macros, preprocessor

As the topic says, I want to be able to run a specific command during build, and have its output be the definition of a preprocessor macro.

Right now, I have several user-defined variables (in project.pbxproj) and I am able to use their values to fill macro definitions, as follows:

GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = (
 "STRINGIFY(x)=@#x",
 "_MACRO=STRINGIFY(${MACRO})",
);
MACRO = foo;

I can set MACRO to a different value per scheme (e.g Debug vs. Release) which is very useful. But, I cannot figure out how to set it by running a command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can think of 3 options:

**Environment variable**: If you build from command line you can export a variable (`export ENVMACRO=superfoo`) before invoking the build command and use it in an Xcode configuration file `OTHER_CFLAGS=-DMACRO=$(ENVMACRO)`. You need to configure the target with the `.xcconfig` file.

**Run Script Build Phase**: Custom script that generates a header file.

```
MACROVALUE=$(run-command-to-obtain-value)
echo "#define MACRO ($MACROVALUE)" > $(SRCROOT)/path/to/header.h
```

In my tests you need an empty header file to be able to compile properly. There are other options like modifying an existing file using `sed` or any other command.

**Custom Build Rule**: Custom script that process an input file and creates an output file. Similar to *Run Script* build phase but slightly better because it will run the script only when the input file has been modified. For example, create a `.macro` file and process it to update a header file.

In Xcode > Target > Build rules, add new custom rule.

*Process*: `*.macro`

Custom script:

```
HEADER="${SRCROOT}/Config.h"
cd ${SRCROOT}
echo "// Do not edit" > $HEADER
cat "${INPUT_FILE_PATH}" | while read line
do
    macro="`echo $line | cut -d= -f1`"
    cmd="`echo $line | cut -d= -f2-`"
    value=$($cmd)
    echo "#define ${macro} @\"${value}\"" >> $HEADER
done
echo "// Updated on "`date` >> $HEADER
```

*Output files*: `$(SRCROOT)/Project.h`

`Project.macro` contains pairs `MACRO=one-liner-command`. Like these two non-sense examples:

```
COMMIT=git log --pretty=format:%h -n 1
BUILDYEAR=date +%Y
```

Generated file will look like:

```
// Do not edit
#define COMMIT @"c486178"
#define BUILDYEAR @"2011"
// Updated on Sat Oct 29 14:40:41 CEST 2011
```

Each time `Project.macro` changes, the generated header will be updated.

Comment: thanks -- the second option is essentially what i've gone with -- in my case, i wanted the command to run at every build. the only wrinkle is that i don't write to the actual header file if its contents aren't identical to the newly generated contents (to avoid the dependency change). i do especially like the third option as well though.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is curious, the solution I've used is to add a new build phase that runs a script that manually generates a header file with the macros that I want. It's not elegant, and I would still prefer something better, but it works.

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  Make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that other may learn from your success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution would be to declare just one preprocessor macro in the project build settings (e.g. `DEBUG` for debug, `RELEASE` for release) and then in your Prefix.pch file you can check for the value in order to decide what other macros to define, e.g.:

```
// Use NSLOG and NSASSERT so that they are only output in debug mode
#ifdef DEBUG

//#warning You are running in Debug mode
#define NSLOG NSLog
#define NSASSERT NSAssert
#define NSASSERT1 NSAssert1

#else

#define NSLOG if(false)NSLog
#define NSASSERT(X, Y)  \
if(!(X)) {          \
NSLogOkay(Y);       \
}                   
#define NSASSERT1(X, Y, Z)  \
if(!(X)) {              \
NSLogOkay(Y, Z);        \
}                       

#endif
```